# Convert javax.servlet.http.Part to java.sql.Blob

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to upload large file using Hibernate into Blob using `javax.servlet.http.Part` by inserting it into `java.sql.Blob`

Can I do this without consuming too much RAM? I want directly when I insert the file to insert it into the database without consuming too much RAM.

I tried this:

```
InputStream input = part.getFile().getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
        for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) output.write(buffer, 0, length);

        blob.setFilePart(output.toByteArray());
```

But as far as I can see the entire file will be stored into RAM. Can you propose some solution?

Comment: Maybe you can read the contents from stream in pieces, store in buffer array, and then keep appending to blob in the database.

Comment: @SandeshGupta Can you show me example how to do it?

Comment: I won't be able to provide an example as I don't have environment setup. Please refer the following link, which has pretty good comments and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923882/how-to-insert-a-huge-file-to-blob-oracle-without-loading-the-complete-file-to